# How to add key value pair to the json?

Tags: javascript, json

I am fetching some json, but i want to add a key value pair to each object inside the array.

[image]

What i want is to add a key value pair to each object inside students array

Comment: run a loop in the object and append add stuff to item

Comment: You can use Array.map. E.g updatedstudents = students.map(student=>({...student, [additionalKey]: additionalValue}))

Comment: @VaibhavVishal yeah i did that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
var students = [ { city: 'California', company: 'ABC'}, { city: 'LA', company: 'PQR'}, { city: 'Mumbai', company: 'XYZ'}];
        
students.forEach((obj) => {
  obj['email']= 'abc@xyz.com';
  console.log(obj);
});

// Final Output
console.log(students);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you simply use a for loop for each element in your array and since it's JSON simply specify a new "key = value" inside the current element.

edit : here's an example :

```
var entreprises = [
     {id: 33, uuid: "3d103130-ae0d-11e9-8e6c-dfb1a3a5afce", nom: "test", adresse: "test", ville: "tes" },
     {id: 34, uuid: "81524090-ae0d-11e9-8894-2326c7695f11", nom: "test2", adresse: "test2", ville: "test2"}];

for (let i = 0; i < entreprises.length; i++) {
    entreprises[i].key = "value";
}
```

Comment: Thank you it was useful

Answer (score 0):

Start by iterating through the students array using either a foreach or standard for loop. This will give you access to each of the students, one by one. Since each of the students is an object, you will have to use either bracket or dot notation to store this new key,value pair. Here is an article that will help you determine which strategy to use for accessing keys and storing key,value pairs: [Bracket notation vs Dot notation](https://medium.com/dailyjs/dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation-eedea5fa8572.)

**Note:** If the key you are adding already exists, you will be overriding the previous value.

**For loop**

```
for (let i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  const student = students[i];
  student[<key>] = <value>;
}
```

**Foreach**

```
students.forEach(student => {
  student[<key>] = <value>;
});
```