# Add a key value pair to an object in a for loop

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am having difficulty getting my for loop to add a new key-value pair to an object. It has no problem changing a current value of a key that already exists but for some reason, it will not add a new one

```
async function test(messagesWithSomeContent) {
  for (i = 0; i < messagesWithSomeContent.length; i++) {
    messagesWithSomeContent[i]["photo"] = 'please add this'; // this does not add a new key value pair
    messagesWithSomeContent[i]["sender"] = 'change this'; // this works
    console.log(messagesWithSomeContent[i]);
  }
  return win(await Promise.all(messagesWithSomeContent));
}

async function win(yay) {
  console.log('yay');
}
```

messageWithSomeContent

```
[ { _id: 5e8f5a6a2582bf629998c3fe,
    sender: '5e8f8d6be541b07ab8d8770b',
    content: { content: 'Welcome to' },
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5e8f594768fdda61d4f2ef6d,
    sender: '5e8f86852c2a5174f3ca5e8c',
    content: { content: 'hello test' },
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5e8f585ee3eaa06136048b5c,
    sender: '5e8f883627154676347fe286',
    content: { lol: 'yeesh' },
    __v: 0 } ]
```

I looked at some [similar posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57182641/how-to-add-key-value-pair-to-the-json) and their solutions are not working.

Comment: What kind of promise do you expect to have in `messagesWithSomeContent `?

Answer (score 0):

i can't add comment to you so i want to comment on this answer
what the output you want ?

```js
async function test(messagesWithSomeContent) {
  for (i = 0; i < messagesWithSomeContent.length; i++) {
    messagesWithSomeContent[i]["photo"] = 'please add this';
    messagesWithSomeContent[i]["sender"] = 'change this';
  }
  return win(await Promise.all(messagesWithSomeContent));
}

async function win(yay) {
  const u = await yay; // tried add this to see the result
  console.log(u)
}
```

tried console.log on here => https://repl.it/repls/RealisticExtralargeAstronomy

Comment: That gives me the same result as my OP. It's not adding any key to the objects :(

Comment: what the result u want, can u tell on your question

Comment: I want the result to be the array in OP but with another line each each object like     `photo: 'example'`.

Comment: you need to tell us about the output on your question!

Comment: did you want the photo key inside of content ?

Comment: try look at this > https://repl.it/repls/AwesomeLimegreenApplescript

Answer (score 0):

With the limited code added here, Try using the spread operator, although using JSFiddle I was able to get yours to work with my own made up sample data.

```
async function test(messagesWithSomeContent) {
   for (i = 0; i < messagesWithSomeContent.length; i++) {
        messagesWithSomeContent[i] = Object.assign({}, messagesWithSomeContent[i], {photo: 'please add this', sender: 'change this'})
        console.log(messagesWithSomeContent[i]);
  }
  return win(await Promise.all(messagesWithSomeContent));
}
```

Comment: That works kinda but it gives me this massive array with like 50 things in it when the original one just had about 3

Comment: All this is doing is taking what is currently in messagesWithSomeContent[i] and copying over the items and adding in the key / value for photo and sender.

Comment: This is what is being logged a few times over https://repl.it/repls/DarkredJadedTwintext

Comment: If that doesn't work it seems like your data might be wrong

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, I'm getting the same giant array with all that info from my replit

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.all` must receive an array of promises. A way of doing this is using `map` over the array of parameters, calling the function on the callback.

```
Promise.all(parameters.map(parameter => myAsyncFunction(parameter)));
```

```js
var messages = [
  {_id: '5e8f5a6a2582bf629998c3fe', sender: '5e8f8d6be541b07ab8d8770b', content: { content: 'Welcome to' }, __v: 0},
  {_id: '5e8f594768fdda61d4f2ef6d', sender: '5e8f86852c2a5174f3ca5e8c', content: { content: 'hello test' }, __v: 0},
  { _id: '5e8f585ee3eaa06136048b5c', sender: '5e8f883627154676347fe286', content: { lol: 'yeesh' }, __v: 0}];

async function test() {
  for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    messages[i]["photo"] = 'please add this';
    messages[i]["sender"] = 'change this';
  }
  var result = await Promise.all(messages.map(el => win(el)));
  console.log(result); // Should contain an array with all responses
}

async function win(param) {
  console.log(param);
  return param.photo;
}

test();
```